# How to merge/sum records by group using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

For example, how can I group the following records by `GroupId` using LINQ, and sum all other columns in each group? (thus merging all rows in each group into one)

```
var list = new List<Foo>()
{ 
    new Foo() { GroupId = 0, ValueA = 10, ValueB = 100 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 30, ValueB = 700 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 40, ValueB = 500 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 80, ValueB = 300 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 }
};
```

Expected result is :

```
| GroupId | ValueA | ValueB |
|---------|--------|--------|
|    0    |   10   |   100  |
|    1    |   70   |   1200 |
|    2    |   120  |   700  |
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.GroupId)
    .Select(g => new { GroupId = g.Key, 
                       ValueA = g.Sum(i => i.ValueA), 
                       ValueB = g.Sum(i => i.ValueB)});
```

or just for fun you can do it within one `GroupBy` call using its overload:

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.GroupId,
       (key, groupedItems) => new {
                                      GroupId = key,
                                      ValueA = groupedItems.Sum(i => i.ValueA),
                                      ValueB = groupedItems.Sum(i => i.ValueB),
                                  });
```

or you can use `Aggregate` to avoid iterating each group many times:

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.GroupId)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((i1, i2) => new Foo{ GroupId = i1.GroupId,
                                                  ValueA = i1.ValueA + i2.ValueA,
                                                  ValueB = i1.ValueB + i2.ValueB,
                                                }));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x=> x.GroupId)
                .Select(g=> new 
                  {
                     GroupId = g.Key, 
                     ValueA = g.Sum(x => x.ValueA), 
                     ValueB = g.Sum(x => x.ValueB)
                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GroupBy` to collect `Foo`s into groups based on their `GroupId`, and then create a new object for each "row" of the result (that object can be a `Foo` itself based on the code you give, but it could just as easily be anything else, including an anonymous type). At that point you will also sum up the other values.

```
var sums = list.GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)
               .Select(g => new Foo
               { 
                   GroupId = g.Key, 
                   ValueA = g.Sum(f => f.ValueA),
                   ValueB = g.Sum(f => f.ValueB)
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the lambda expressions (almost) and using a "purely" LINQ way:

```
var sums = from foo in list
    group foo by foo.GroupId into groupings
    orderby groupings.Key ascending
    select new
    {
        GroupId = groupings.Key,
        ValueA = groupings.Sum(g => g.ValueA),
        ValueB = groupings.Sum(g => g.ValueB)
    };
```

I just think LINQ is a bit more natural-language looking, as compared to lambda (not that there's anything wrong with that...)